# how to install rosserial in jade

Tags: rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i am using ROS Jade and want to communicate with my arduino robot using bluetooth for this purpose i require to install the rosserial package i use the following command but receive an error

sudo apt-get install ros-jade-rosserial-arduino

ERROR:
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-jade-rosserial-client/ros-jade-rosserial-client_0.7.1-0trusty-20151110-1446-+0000_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-jade-rosserial-arduino/ros-jade-rosserial-arduino_0.7.1-0trusty-20151110-1449-+0000_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

similarly many other file are not found

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226598/how-to-install-rosserial-in-jade/) by [naqi.nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/25464/naqi.nick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2016-02-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i couldnt solve the issue but i found a way around i used the 2nd method given in the ROS.org website and installed it manually from github.

http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Arduino%20IDE%20Setup
its the "3.1.2 Installing from Source onto the ROS workstation"

---

Originally posted by [naqi.nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/25464/naqi.nick/) with karma: 62 on 2016-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2016-03-10**:
Not all packages are available on all platforms. I don't think rosserial_arduino has been released into jade.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2016-03-10**:
I see [rosserial_arduino is released into Jade already](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_jade_default.html?q=rosserial_arduino)?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2016-03-10**:
Then @naqu.nick should check what platform he's trying to install onto.